# Bar or cafe open 24 hours in Bucharest

Tags: food-and-drink, bucharest

We have a flight that arrives to Bucharest very late (2am, weekday). Then we have a train at 7am. We don't want to pay for an hotel just to stay 3 or 4 hours, but we still don't want to stay waiting in the street.

Is there any bar or coffee shop open 24 hours in Bucharest?

Comment: Google Maps lets you filter by opening hours. It gave me a number of pubs and clubs that are open until 5 or 6 (even on a Tuesday). I can't personally recommend one because I've never been there :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several well known fast food restaurants in the train station itself open early (McDonald's - 04:30) or are open 24/7 (Springtime).

If you're after a bar, [Oktoberfest](https://goo.gl/maps/xQz8aDtpwVTueogi8) is a well known one that is open until 05:00, and nearby [Bound](https://goo.gl/maps/WXAPx8hDmS77UAQU7) closes at 06:00. However be aware that they are not close to the train station.

Realistically your best options are in the Old Town, but most bars are closed by 02:00, so you'll need to look hard on Google Maps. I wouldn't recommend trying or exploring the area outside the train station, because it's not a particularly good one.

Comment: And I also think that Brauhaus restaurant is opened until 5 AM or so.